# How to integrate with SAP B1 using DI Server integration?

Tags: integration, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

We are trying to integrate SAP business one to our application using Java

Where can we find more information on it any Documents, API , tutorial, links, how to start/do it pointer towards the right direction will be appreciated.

SAP's Developer portal if more focused on SAP HANA - http://go.sap.com/developer.html?original_fqdn=developers.sap.com

We are considering to use DI server to integrate from the below list?
We cannot use SAP HANA platform.

-DI API,
-DI Server,
-B1WS,
-SAP Business One Service Layer

Thank you for your help and time

Answer (score 4):

The Business One installer has an option to install an SDK component. This contains a CHM format help file containing information on DI-API, DI-Server and UI-API (but not Service Layer <strike>which is for Hana version only</strike>) as well as database schema. Also in the SDK are example projects in VB and C#.

If you are using DI-Server, calling the GetBusinessObjectXmlSchema method will get you the schema for individual object types such as business partners.

DI-Server is more lightweight but has less functionality than DI-API. It is more suited to transactional processing such as importing orders from a website.

If you do need to use Service Layer, it's functions are based on DI-API and there should be a lot of concepts that apply to both.

Comment: One detail about DI-API vs DI-Server is that DI API was designed to be used with .NET-based applications (using Visual Studio) whereas the DI-Server is technology-stack agnostic. In your case I would go with the DI Server since you're looking to integrate using Java.

Answer (score 3):

B1WS is not stable and has lots of bugs.  DI Server is difficult to be integrated with.  You could use DI API to do the integration but you have to implement the integration layer with .net platform.  Since you need to make the communication work between SAP B1 and your JAVA application, here is another option which should be a feasible solution.  Please check the following Python flask RESTful application which is top on SAP B1 DI to enable the RESTful capability for integration with SAP B1.

https://github.com/ideabosque/SAP-B1-RESTful

Here is the detail about how it could be used to integrate between eCommerce and SAP B1.
http://ideabosque.postach.io/post/how-to-use-sap-b1-restful-to-integrate-with-ecommerce-platforms

What is your workflow to integrate between SAP B1 and the JAVA application?

Bibo W.

Answer (score 1):

Di_server is oriented mainly to web products, since it allows multiple connections with one license per server, while di-api is more oriented to desktop applications and uses licenses per user.
This means that with di-server you have a license and can connect multiple users simultaneously, while with di-api you have a license you can only connect one user at a time. Of course you can use a license and manage connection times to users, connected to one and making others wait. Or if you have more di-api licenses connect more users as many licenses as you have. The cost of a di-server license is high, but it is offset against the amount of licenses you would have to buy for di-api by users you want to connect to, if you need them all to be connected to SAP BO.

Comment: Remember that DI-API can be assigned an Indirect Access license, rather than a full Professional license.