# Does the SAP B1 Service Layer require HANA backend?

Tags: sapb1, service-layer

In the available documentation about the **Service Layer** I have read, that there is a requirement to run a HANA backend, if the **Service Layer** is to be used. This info can be found *e.g.* here:

- https://help.sap.com/doc/0d2533ad95ba4ad7a702e83570a21c32/9.3/en-US/Working_with_SAP_Business_One_Service_Layer.pdf (the document is labelled *for SAP HANA* as well, I am not finding one without such a descriptor)

However in a different [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40283857/7447660) I have seen a similar comment, referring to the HANA requirement, which was later crossed out:

> The Business One installer has an option to install an SDK component. This contains a CHM format help file containing information on DI-API, DI-Server and UI-API (but not Service Layer <s>which is for Hana version only</s>) as well as database schema.

There is however no further explanation as to why. So my question then is:

**Does the Service Layer for SAP B1 require a HANA backend or is that not a valid requirement (anymore)?**

Comment: Nope, you can use SQL Server backend only with SAP B1 version 10 and upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From This Document regarding features and upgrades for SAP b1 Version 10

https://help.sap.com/doc/1e149715909a4d8ea8920df5513eb64c/10.0/en-US/SAP_Business_One_10.0_Highlights.pdf

on page 5 under Platform | Extensibility it says:

> Service Layer Enable for Microsoft SQL Server

[image: Sap B1 10 Features]

There is also an Updated Version of the Document you posted, which contains multiple examples for Microsoft Sql Server.

**Working with SAP Business One Service Layer**

version 1.23:
https://help.sap.com/doc/6ab840ef2e8140f3af9eeb7d8fef9f06/10.0/en-US/Working_with_SAP_Business_One_Service_Layer.pdf

so HANA is no longer a requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the info as well as the references, answer is accepted.